# Is it possible to submit multiple forms with post-action with one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

i have several forms with the same action on one page.
The number of forms is variable.

Every form itself has a post-action e.g.
When i'm on the page 1 and submit the first form it sends

```
page/1/par_one/1/para_values
```

to the controller. Form 2 does:

```
page/1/par_two/2/para_values
```

etc.

What i tried now is that i give every form the same class.
When i click the button it should submit all forms. The bad thing is, that only the last form is submitted every time.

My code for the submit-action look like this:

```
<script>
$( "#button_for_all_submits" ).click(function() {
    $( ".forms_who_should_submitted" ).each(function() {
        $( this ).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: You can only submit one form at a time. To do what you require you need to submit each form using AJAX.

Comment: What do you think about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7998096/3623608). I try around with this but doesn't work yet.

Comment: Oh now it works :) thank you guys for the fast comments with Ajax. `+1` if i could!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rory McCrossan` is right (from the comments) - when you submit a form through HTML, it sends the form's `inputs` as parameters to your server's `endpoint` (the `action` element of the form):

--

From [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp):

> HTML forms send data to a server. The data is sent to the page
>   specified in the form's action attribute. The file defined in the
>   action attribute usually does something with the received input

The problem you face is that submitting a form only sends the data for *that* form to *that* action endpoint. Nothing more & nothing less - it's part of the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

--

If you want to send two sets of data, you'll have to therefore send an [asynchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) to your server. This is handled with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: This conclusion. Solution for my problem:
`$('form').each(function() {var that = $(this); $.post(that.attr('action'), that.serialize());
});` from [this Stackoverflow-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998050/submitting-multiple-forms-with-ajax/7998096#7998096)