# Submit Multiple Form to a File with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi We have multiple form which will submit to a single page using ajax and that data will be inserted to database :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return insertData()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_id" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_id :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_id" value="122" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seokey" class="control-label col-sm-2">seokey :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="trackseo" value="Are Wah" id="trackseo" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_title" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_title" value="Are Wah tu Bhi" id="trackTitle" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
  </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return insertData()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_id" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_id :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_id" value="122" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seokey" class="control-label col-sm-2">seokey :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="trackseo" value="Are Wah" id="trackseo" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_title" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_title" value="Are Wah tu Bhi" id="trackTitle" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
  </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return insertData()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_id" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_id :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_id" value="122" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seokey" class="control-label col-sm-2">seokey :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="trackseo" value="Are Wah" id="trackseo" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_title" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_title" value="Are Wah tu Bhi" id="trackTitle" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
  </div>
</form>
```

and below is the javascript function from where we will call the ajax function :

```
function insertData() {
  callToAjax();
  return false
}

function callToAjax() {
  //using XMLHttp submit data
}
```

but i don't know how we will send data of all forms.
Thanks For Advance.

Comment: With the `click` of a `input type="submit"` you can submit only one `form` at a time.. plus you have given `input type="submit"` for button `cancel` too which also submits the `form`

Answer (score 0):

Similar post [submitting multiple forms with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998050/submitting-multiple-forms-with-ajax)

Name them differently and submit them like this,

```
<script>
    function submitAll() {
        document.form-horizontal1.submit();
        document.form-horizontal2.submit();
        document.form-horizontal3.submit();
    }
</script>
```